# Pinescript: Function inside a function

Tags: pine-script

I am trying create three functions inside a main function but am getting syntax error in input in the lines where I am defining these functions.

```
customFunc() => 
////////
data(x, id) => security(id, mtf_val!="" ? mtf_val : timeframe.period, x)
    getLow(x, y, z, a, id) => 
       ll = y
       v = data(x, id)
       m = v==ll or data(z, id) - v > a*syminfo.mintick
       if v!=ll
           ll := v
       if m
           v := 0.0
       [v,ll]
    getHigh(x, y, z, a, id) => 
       lh = y
       v = data(x, id)
       m = v==lh or v - data(z, id) > a*syminfo.mintick
       if v!=lh
          lh := v
       if m
          v := 0.0
       [v,lh]
```

Getting syntax error in the 3rd, 4th and 13th line. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pine does not support sub-functions being defined within other functions.
All functions must be defined separately in the global scope.
See [Declaring Functions](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Declaring_functions.html#) in the user manual.